# Is GoogleMock still intended to work with any testing framework?

Tags: c++, testing, googlemock

Until v 1.8.1, [Using Google Mock with Any Testing Framework](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/refs/tags/release-1.8.1/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md#using-google-mock-with-any-testing-framework) was documented.

Since v 1.10.x, it looks like this section does not appear in the documentation. Has it been moved somewhere else or GoogleMock is no more made to work with any testing framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has it been moved somewhere else or GoogleMock is no more made to work with any testing framework?

The section has been removed.

The commit

- [Preparation for including docs in round-trip with OSS](https://github.com/google/googletest/commit/31ff59788846d173aba856d143aebf4b68ea4602)

of the [googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest) project [entirely removed](https://github.com/google/googletest/commit/31ff59788846d173aba856d143aebf4b68ea4602#diff-753b78d9752454b972f2b46f8b271b03L171) the section *Using Google Mock with Any Testing Framework*. The commit is large in scope, however, and contains several other changes to the documentation, and there is no particular explanation (nor review comments) as for why this section was cut out.

If you want an answer from the author of the commit (who also is the main author of gtest), I would suggest [opening an issue](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues) on project.